Error when adding fingerprint for authentication
i tried to add a fingerprint for authentication, but it gives an error.

Translated Error Message: "Failed to reserve the ElanTech Fingerprint Sensor: the device is already reserved by another process"
I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1. I am using an Acer Aspire 7 laptop.

Sorry for the many mistakes. I'm new here and downloaded Ubuntu only today. I'm only 14 and I'm bad at grammar cuz my native language us Ukrainian

Never apologize for mistakes, we're all here to help where we can :)  And thank you for at least translating the Russian as best as you can, it helps those of us who are in other regions of the world to properly understand what's actually going on :)
